# Naive questions on AdS/CFT dictionary and alternatives?

Tags: ads-cft, holographic-principle, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I'm starting to become curious about [AdS/CFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdS/CFT_correspondence) since hearing that condensed matter theorists use it as a 'dictionary' to find gravity duals of things from condensed matter physics. How exactly does this dictionary work?
Also, are there other promising theories that link gravity in bulk to a conformal field theory at the boundary, just like AdS/CFT? And could the same dictironary be used there?

Comment: AdS/CFT is a framework that connects a class of gravitational theories (that are all asymptotically AdS) to a class of quantum field theories in one lower dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Not just condensed matter people, but also the folks doing high energy physics. And as of your question of linking a theory of quantum gravity to a CFT (not on "the" boundary in the conventional sense since the boundary for AdS/CFT was very convenient for a lot of reasons, mainly that in the sense of holographic entanglement entropy you can make a bulk-boundary duality from a minimal spacelike surface joining the boundary points), this is simply what holography is, relating a bulk quantum gravity theory in $D$ dimensions to a boundary CFT on a $D-1$ boundary. For de Sitter, this is $\mathcal{I}^{\pm }$ (although the CFT lives on only one large $S^{D}$) naturally. However, this has several complications, like complex-valued entanglement entropy due to a non-unitary CFT, density matrices being transition matrices, no proper "nice" idea of subregion duality, etc. But there is static patch holography, where the pode-antipode system is related to stretched horizon degrees of freedom in the static patch picture. And so on. The point is, there *are* other examples of dualities, but they are not quite as convenient as AdS/CFT. The bottom-line therefore, is, there are, but at the cost of simplicity. This is an exciting prospect, but it is much messier than AdS/CFT.